# error occured while conneting with database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, dll

```
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it

extension=php_mysql.dll

extension=php_mysqli.dll

;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
```

this is where i have uncommented my /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini but I still get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in /var/www/html/codeigniter/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line 136

I am totally stuck here can any give me the solution for this.

This is my phpinfo() result:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.0/apache2

Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

Scan this dir for additional .ini files   /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d

Additional .ini files parsed      etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
PHP API

Comment: If you are using phpMyadmin,Are you able to access it with the specified login settings for database in database.php